# The constructor ArrayAdapter<List<String>>(Context, int, List<String>) is undefined

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result){
   // here i will make adapter
   List<String> list = result;
   adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<List<String>> (getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
   listV2.setAdapter(adapter2);
}
```

Error shows "The constructor ArrayAdapter>(Context, int, List) is undefined" Why?, What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

`adapter2` should be an `ArrayAdapter<String>`, not an `ArrayAdapter<List<String>>`:

```
adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```